# Change navBar color in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to change the color of the navBar in a fluidPage that contains the navbarPage while also changing the background color of the page itself? For example, I'd like to change the color of my navBar to green, but the color of the rest of the entire page to light grey.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *css* to change look and layout.

```
fluidPage(theme = "styles.css",...)
```

or

```
tags$head(
     tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css")
),
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that I am using a shinyTheme, so I would probably need to do it in the tags$head( ... ) part. Do you know if this is possible / what code I would use to change the colors?

Comment: Then check this site https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/ section "How to use other Bootstrap themes".